# Fill or Clear cells based on surrounding cells

Tags: javascript

I am writing a program that detects cells in a table that are colored blue and adds or removes color to cells. It decides how to treat each cell based on the background color of the cells around it.

Or it's supposed to, but I can't get it to, for each cell, look at how many cells around it are blue to set that cell's class in preparation for the function that clears or fills it.

**Problem** 
I have been unable to have a loop count the blue cells around a cell (zCount), to set its class based on zCount.

**Attempted solution**

```
function zombieRadar(rowIndex, cellIndex) {
    //Checks surrounding cells to determine number of highlighted neighbors
    'use strict';
    zCount = 0;
    for (y = rowIndex - 1; y < rowIndex + 2; y += 1) {
        for (x = cellIndex - 1; x < cellIndex + 2; x += 1) {
            console.log("y:",y, "x:", x, ":", rows[y].cells[x].innerHTML)
            if (rows[y].cells[x].style.backgroundColor === "blue") {
                zCount = zCount + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log("zCount is: " + zCount);

}
```

**Desired results**
for each cell in the table, count adjacent blue cells, and set the cells class to live or die based on zCount.

Javascript

```
var rows, maxY, maxX, zCount, y, x, idVar;
var cellPositionX = 2,
    cellPositionY = 2;

//From Stackoverflow user Ruben Decrop to remove 'console' is undefined warning
var console = console || {};
console.log = console.log || function () {
    'use strict';
};

function zombieRadar(rowIndex, cellIndex) {
    //Checks surrounding cells to determine number of highlighted neighbors
    'use strict';
    zCount = 0;
    for (y = rowIndex - 1; y < rowIndex + 2; y += 1) {
        for (x = cellIndex - 1; x < cellIndex + 2; x += 1) {
            console.log("y:",y, "x:", x, ":", rows[y].cells[x].innerHTML)
            if (rows[y].cells[x].style.backgroundColor === "blue") {
                zCount = zCount + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log("zCount is: " + zCount);

} //works

function toggleCell(ev) {
    //toggle cell manually
    'use strict';
    var rowIndex = ev.parentElement.rowIndex,
        cellIndex = ev.cellIndex;
    //console.log('Row = ' + rowIndex + ', Column = ' + cellIndex);
    zombieRadar(rowIndex, cellIndex);

    if (ev.style.backgroundColor === "") {
        ev.innerHTML = '';
        ev.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    } else {
        ev.innerHTML = '';
        ev.style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
} //works

function addClicks() {
    //make cells clickable
    function toggle() {
        toggleCell(this);
    }
    for (y = 0; y < maxY; y += 1) {
        for (x = 0; x < maxX; x += 1) {
            rows[y].cells[x].addEventListener("click", toggle);
            idVar = x + "_" + y;
            rows[y].cells[x].setAttribute("id", idVar);
        }
    }

}

function validPosition(xPosition, yPosition) {
    //make sure we don't perform actions outside of grid
    'use strict';
    if (xPosition > -1 && xPosition < maxX) {
        if (yPosition > -1 && yPosition < maxY) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
} //works

function init() {
    //get our bearings and mark initial cell
    'use strict';
    rows = document.getElementById("grid").rows;
    maxY = rows.length;
    maxX = rows[1].cells.length;
    rows[cellPositionY].cells[cellPositionX].innerHTML = "";
    rows[cellPositionY].cells[cellPositionX].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    addClicks();
} //works

function senseCell() {
    'use strict';
    var xChange = -1,
        yChange = -1;
    for (xChange = -1; xChange < 2; xChange += 1) {
        for (yChange = -1; yChange < 2; yChange += 1) {
            if (validPosition(cellPositionX + xChange, cellPositionY + yChange) && rows[cellPositionY + yChange].cells[cellPositionX + xChange].innerHTML === 'M') {
                return [xChange, yChange];
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
} //works

function moveCell() {
    //move focus cell up, down, left, or right
    //mouse chase capability not yet removed, but no way to add mouse
    'use strict';
    var randomNum = Math.random(),
        xChange = 0,
        yChange = 0,
        cellDirection = senseCell();
    if (randomNum < 0.25) {
        yChange = -1;
    } else if (randomNum < 0.50) {
        xChange = 1;
    } else if (randomNum < 0.75) {
        yChange = 1;
    } else {
        xChange = -1;
    }
    if (validPosition(cellPositionX + xChange, cellPositionY + yChange)) {
        rows[cellPositionY].cells[cellPositionX].innerHTML = "";
        if (cellDirection) {
            xChange = cellDirection[0];
            yChange = cellDirection[1];
        }
        cellPositionX = cellPositionX + xChange;
        cellPositionY = cellPositionY + yChange;
        rows[cellPositionY].cells[cellPositionX].innerHTML = '';
        rows[cellPositionY].cells[cellPositionX].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }
} //works

function quarantine() {
    //clear the zombies from all the cells
    'use strict';
    rows = document.getElementById("grid").rows;
    for (y = 0; y < rows.length; y += 1) {
        for (x = 0; x < rows[0].cells.length; x += 1) {
            rows[y].cells[x].style.backgroundColor = "";
        }
    }
} //works

function scanCity() {
    //check zombie count and mark the cells to clear or fill
    'use strict';
    for (y = 0; y < maxY; y += 1) {
        for (x = 0; x < maxX; x += 1) {
            zombieRadar(y, x);

            if (rows[y].cells[x].style.backgroundColor === "blue"){
                if (zCount < 2) {
                    rows[y].cells[x].className += "die";
                    } else if (zCount === 3) {
                    rows[y].cells[x].className += "live";
                    } else if (zCount > 3) {
                    rows[y].cells[x].className += "die";
                    }
                } else {
                    if (zCount === 3) {
                    rows[y].cells[x].className += "live";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

function processZombie(){
    //clear or fill the cells as marked in scanCity
    'use strict';
    rows = document.getElementById("grid").rows;
    for (y = 0; y < rows.length; y += 1) {
        for (x = 0; x < rows[0].cells.length; x += 1) {
            if (rows[y].cells[x].className = "die") {
                rows[y].cells[x].style.backgroundColor = "";
            } else if (rows[y].cells[x].className = "live") {
                rows[y].cells[x].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
            }
        }
    }
} //works

function smallBatch() {
    //add zombies to specific set of cells
    'use strict';
    rows[5].cells[5].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    rows[5].cells[7].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    rows[6].cells[6].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    rows[6].cells[7].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    rows[7].cells[6].style.backgroundColor = "blue";

    rows[14].cells[6].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    rows[14].cells[7].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    rows[14].cells[7].style.backgroundColor = "blue";

    rows[12].cells[15].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    rows[12].cells[16].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    rows[13].cells[15].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    rows[13].cells[16].style.backgroundColor = "blue";

    rows[14].cells[17].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    rows[14].cells[18].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    rows[15].cells[17].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    rows[15].cells[18].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    console.log("Zombies have been added.")
} //works

function looseZombie() {
    //run the scan and then activate/deactivate cells as needed
    scanCity();
    processZombie();
    console.log("Zombies should have moved.")
}

//conways game of life
//go through and mark cells to live or dispatchEvent
//go through again to actually kill or raise

//auto button, set interval for evolving
//add stop function to Quarantine to shut off interval
```

CSS

```
input,
button {
    display:inline-grid;
    justify-content: space-between;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    margin: 10px;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
}

html {
    background: url("http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dm52438/assets/AdobeStock_147432054.jpeg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

header {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}

body {
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: left;
}

h1 {
    color: white;
    font-family: Garamond, "Book Antiqua", sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    left: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 30px 0;
    position: relative;
}

h2 {
    color: white;
    font-family: Garamond, "Book Antiqua", sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    text-align: center;
}

button {
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

nav {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul {
    background-color: #f78501;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 0 0 200px;
}

nav li a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav li :hover {
    background-color: #835D0E;
    color: #eff260;
}

footer p {
    background-color: #f78501;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 5px 0;
    position: fixed;
}

aside {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    overflow: auto;
    position:relative;
    width: auto;
}

aside div {
    display: inline-block;
}

section {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

aside,
section {
    margin: 5%;
    padding: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

section p {
    padding: 0;
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
}

/* dropdown menu styles */
ul {
    background-color: #333;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #835D0E;
    color: #eff260;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    background-color: #835D0E;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: none;
    min-width: 160px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    display: block;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #835D0E;
    color: #eff260;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

table,
th,
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-color: aliceblue;
}

td {
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25px;
}

button {
    width: 15%;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Evolution</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body onload="init()">
    <header>
        <h1>Zombie Outbreak</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="section" href="http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dm52438/" title="Home">Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">JavaScript</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dm52438/web1430/as01/as01.html">Xmas</a>
                        <a href="http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dm52438/web1430/as02/as02.html">Ultimate Xmas</a>
                        <a href="http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dm52438/web1430/as03/as03.html">Roshambo</a>
                        <a href="http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dm52438/web1430/as04/as04.html">Total War: Roshambo</a>
                        <a href="http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dm52438/web1430/as05/as05.html">Multiplication Quiz</a>
                        <a href="http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dm52438/web1430/as06/as06.html">Costello's Pasta</a>
                        <a href="http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dm52438/web1430/as08/as08.html">Evolution</a>
                        <a href="http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dm52438/web1430/as09/as09.html">Item List</a>
                        <a href="http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dm52438/web1430/as10/as10.html">Refactored Item List</a>
                        <a href="http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dm52438/web1430/as11/as11.html">Flash Cards</a>
                        <a href="http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dm52438/web1430/as12/as12.html">Bookstore</a>
                        <a href="http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dm52438/web1430/final/final.html">Final</a>
                        <a href="http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dm52438/web1430/bonus/bonus01.html">Gradebook Sorting</a>
                        <a href="http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dm52438/web1430/bonus/bonus02.html">20 Questions</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li><a href="http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dm52438/saltmods/" target="_self" title="Web Fundementals Page">Web Fundementals</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dm52438/solarHTML.html" target="_self" title="Solar Calculator">Solar Calculator</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </main>

    <section>
        <div id="table">
            <table id="grid" class="a">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <button onclick="looseZombie()">Loose Zombie</button>
        <button onclick="smallBatch()">Small Outbreak</button>
        <button onclick="autoMove()">Large Outbreak</button>
        <button onclick="quarantine()">Quarantine</button>
    </section>
    <aside>
        In "Evolution (a metaphor)" cells come into being, persist and perish depending on how many live cells are adjacent to them. Here are the rules they live and die by:
            <li>If a live cell has less than two living neighbours*, it perishes</li>
            <li>If a live cell has two or three living neighbours it continues to live</li>
            <li>If a live cell has more than three living neighbours, it perishes</li>
            <li>If a dead cell has exactly three living neighbours, it comes into being</li>
            <li>*When a cell touches the corner or side of another cell they are neighbors</li>
    </aside>
    <footer class="center">
        <p></p>
    </footer>
    <script src="javascriptAs08.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey will you please add html and css in question?

Comment: Sure thing, that you for the comment.

Comment: also re edit the question Like "List the problems you are facing , List the solutions you have tried , List the desired results"

Comment: Thanks again, I tried to make it more clear.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function zombieRadar(rowIndex, cellIndex) {
    //Checks surrounding cells to determine number of highlighted neighbors
    'use strict';
    let row=rowIndex;
    let col=cellIndex;
    zCount = 0;
    if (!(row - 1 < 0)) {
        if (rows[row - 1].cells[col].className === "live") {
            zcount++;
        }
    }
    if (!(row + 1 > totalRows - 1)) {
        if (rows[row + 1].cells[col].className === "live") {
            zcount++;
        }
    }
    if (!(col - 1 < 0)) {
        if (rows[row].cells[col - 1].className === "live") {
            zcount++;
        }
    }
    if (!(col - 1 < 0) && !(row - 1 < 0)) {
        if (rows[row - 1].cells[col - 1].className === "live") {
            zcount++;
        }
    }
    if (!(col + 1 > totalColumns - 1)) {
        if (rows[row].cells[col + 1].className === "live") {
            zcount++;
        }
    }
    if (!(col + 1 > totalColumns - 1) && !(row + 1 > totalRows - 1)) {
        if (rows[row + 1].cells[col + 1].className === "live") {
            zcount++;
        }
    }
    if (!(col + 1 > totalColumns - 1) && !(row - 1 < 0)) {
        if (rows[row - 1].cells[col + 1].className === "live") {
            zcount++;
        }
    }
    if (!(row + 1 > totalRows - 1) && !(col - 1 < 0)) {
        if (rows[row + 1].cells[col - 1].className === "live") {
            zcount++;
        }
    }
    console.log("zCount is: " + zCount);
    return zcount;
}
```